# Kotlin - Obfuscated Property Names

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

I'm developing a Kotlin Android app and I'm having an issue integrating Google Sign In, when I get the GoogleSignInAccount in order to extract properties, the property names seem to be obfuscated (or otherwise jumbled up), here's a screenshot of the way the properties look on AS 2.3 debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Here's the snippet of code that tries to access those properties:

```
 private fun googleSignInResult(data : GoogleSignInResult) {
    if (data.isSuccess) {
        if (data.signInAccount != null) {
            val account = data.signInAccount
            val authData = HashMap<String, String>()

            authData["id_token"] = account?.idToken.let { it } ?: return
            authData["id"] = account?.id.let { it } ?: return

            val task = ParseUser.logInWithInBackground("google", authData)

            task.continueWith { user ->
                if (task.isCancelled) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User cancelled Google login")
                } else if (task.isFaulted) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + task.error)
                } else {
                    this.user = task.result
                    this.user?.put("email", account?.email)
                    this.user?.put("name", account?.displayName)
                    this.user?.put("firstName", account?.displayName)

                    this.user?.saveInBackground({ error ->
                        if(error != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.message)
                            this.user?.deleteInBackground()
                            ParseUser.logOutInBackground()
                        } else {
                            //Logged in successfully
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on why is it that properties look like that?, when I try to access idToken or id they're always null, however, the property names that are "obfuscated" can't be accessed, is this a kotlin bug or is it my error?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: fields != properties. You're on JVM, what you see in the debugger are obfuscated fields. The getters are public and retain original names. Java `.getDisplayName()` = `.displayName` in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following content is originally posted by @EugenPechanec as a comment to the question body. Some modification is applied to promote reading experience.*

---

*Fields*, a term from JVM, is not *properties*, which is a Kotlin term. You're on JVM, and what you see in the debugger are obfuscated fields backing the Kotlin properties. The getters are public and retain original names. Java `.getDisplayName()` is *.displayName* in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clarification @EugenPechanec, however, I already tried that and it doesn't work, doing the following: `account?.idToken` (the kotlin getter) or `account?.getIdToken()` (the Java getter) both return null, that's why I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is